# Responsive images size and div disappearing when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want make two `div`s: *image* and *description for image*. If there is not enough space for 100% image size, this image must be smaller. Description `div` should have a fixed size on the right of the image.

In my code, if I reduce browser width the `div` with the image description moves under the image instead of staying to the right.

How I can fix this?

```css
.parentdiv
{
    width:100%; 
    height: auto; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.imgdiv
{
    width:auto; 
    border: 1px solid green; 
    float: left
}
.textdiv
{
    width: 200px; 
    height: 400px; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    float: left
}
.imgdiv img
{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
     
    <div class="parentdiv">
        <div class="imgdiv">
            <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png">
        </div>
        <div class="textdiv">
            Description 
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>         
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this : [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/963xL575/)

CSS:

```
.parentdiv {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.imgdiv {
    margin-right:210px;
}
.imgdiv img {
    width:100%;
}
.textdiv {
    width:200px;
    float:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parentdiv">
    <div class="textdiv">Description</div>
    <div class="imgdiv">
        <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If available you can use the CSS3 functionality `calc()`.
Set a `min-width` of `100%` on the image, and reduce it with the `200px` of the right div.

Like so

`max-width: calc(100% - 200px);`

Also, I set a `border-box` on the elements with a border so it all fits. Keep in mind that when you add padding to these elements now, the element does not increase in size.

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mhts08a/)***